# jQuery delegate focusout or blur event

Tags: jquery

I have the next code declared in my on ready:

```js
jQuery("body").delegate(".ta_obsn", "focusout", function() {
  alert("Fired method");
  jQuery(".tas")
    .append('<textarea type="text" class="form-control" class="ta_observacion"></textarea>');
});
```

This problems occurs with the `focusout` and `blur` methods, but if I replace the `change`instead `focusout` the method is fired.

How I can use `focousout` using delegate (or similar behavior)?

Comment: It will be better if you provide the HTML you're using. Maybe this is related with some parent/child limitation of `focusout`/`blur` event or even jquery version

Comment: `delegate()` is being replaced with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the signature is: `$("selector").on("event", "data", function() {...`

Comment: `$("body").on("focusout",".ta_obsn", function() ...`

Comment: @mplungjan if you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We nowadays [delegate with .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), in your case

```
$("body").on("focusout",".ta_obsn", function() ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate has been deprecated we now use the .on() instead
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

seems fine with the none deprecated '.on()' method

```js
 $("input").on("focusout", function() {
        $("div").append('focusout invoked ! ');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  
</div>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use .on with latest jQuery:

```
$('body').on('blur','.ta_obsn',function(){
//Your code goes here
});
```